# How to mark HTML DOM TextNode

Tags: html, dom, textnode, xmldom

I am populating all TextNodes in a page, posting their nodeValues to a remote site with an ajax query. When the associated callback is invoked, I want to somehow mark the TextNode fed to the callback function but the attributes of TextNode seem to be immutable except nodeValue.

A number of options that I can think of now are somehow to mark nodeValue without changing the seen text-using a non-printable character? or wrapping the TextNode object/class, removing it from dom tree and reinjecting it back to the dom tree?

Are these doable? Do you have any (other) ideas?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Another idea I could think of is to populate an array with objects in the form `{'element': text element, 'read': 0}`. When you read in a textNode, do a loop on all the objects in the array until you find one that matches the `element` property. Then set the `read` value to 1. If you want to check and see if a text element has been read, you'll need to once again loop through the array until you find one that matches the `element` property and see what the `read` value is. This will get expensive if you have a lot of text nodes.

Comment: well yes. it seems to be a quite expensive sol'n. how about wrapping TextNodes? how can I wrap a TextNode?